# AWS and NodeJS architecture for a scheduled/cron task in multi server setup

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ses, node-redis

I am using AWS services in deploying my application which currently has the production site setup on an application load balancer running 2 instances of my NodeJS server.

My current concern is if I just setup a `node-cron` to trigger a task at 5:00am, it will do this for each server I spin up.

I need to implement an email delivery system where at 5:00am it will query my database table I made to generate customized emails (need to iterate over each individual;s record which has a unique array that helps build a list of items for each user). I then fire the object off to AWS SES.

What's are some ways you have done this?

- **Currently based off my readings I am looking at two options:
- **

Setup a node-cron child process within one cluster (but if I have auto-scaling, wouldn't this create a duplicate node-cron task), but this would probably require Redis and tracking the process across servers

OR

Setup an EventBridge API which fires an `api.mybackendserver.com/send-email-event` where I then carry out my logic.  (this seems like the simpler approach, and the drawbacks would be potential CPU/RAM spikes which would be fine as i'm regionally based and would do this in off-peak hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventBridge is definitely a way to go with CRON. If you're worried about usage spikes you could use CRON to invoke a Lambda function. That pushes events to SQS for each job. Those would be polled by EC2 instances.

Other way would be to schedule a task to increase number of instances before cron event occurs.

Comment: Thanks Karjan, appreciate the input, I will read up more on EventBridge.

Comment: So for the CRON + Lambda + SQS: I create a CRON that invokes a LAMBDA Function. 

In my Lambda function I can query my database table and build an event which I then pass to my SQS which is consumed by an EC2 instance. 

With this EC2 instance, do I schedule a task to spin up this server and process the events, then shut it down when finished?

Comment: Those are separate options. First: CRON invokes Lambda, lambda fetches jobs from Database, finds there are 1000 jobs so publishes event per job to SQS. Your EC2 are polling data for SQS and you can define on how many threads those should work, or how long to wait before fetching next event to process (so your instances won't get overwhelmed)
Second: You could schedule a scale-up event in your autoscaling group to add additional instance to handle load (it's a autoscaling group feature, not EventBridge CRON)

Comment: Thank you, I will read up on these options. Much appreciated Karjan!